# Git Hash value of last un-pushed local commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-hash

I have 3 local commits on my branch mainline which are ahead of the remote repo. How to get the hash value of the earliest local commit?

> Example:
>
> A <- HEAD(mainline) local
> B
> C
> D <- origin/mainline synced with remote

How to get hash value of commit C?

Comment: Why do you need the hash value. You can use HEAD~2

Comment: Is there any other purpose for you needing the hash value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log --pretty=%H origin/master..HEAD |tail -n1`

Comment: Thanks for the exact answer.

Comment: If the set of commits has a branch-and-merge in it, add `--topo-order`, though for most cases this is major overkill. :-)